# Cannot turn off built-in Mac iSight camera in Windows

Tags: windows, camera, webcam

Recently I am developing video-related programs in Windows platform under a MacBook Pro 15″ Retina (mid 2014). The programs usually have functions to turn on the iSight camera to capture images. However, I found that even if the program has been closed, the camera was still on, which could be seen from 2 aspects:

1. If I re-run the program, the camera cannot be turned on again.
2. The green light beside the camera is always on.

This phenomenon doesn't exist if I run the same code under OS X.

So how can I manually or automatically turn off the iSight Camera in Windows for a MacBook?

Comment: Are you using Boot Camp? Did you install the Boot Camp drivers?

Comment: Yes, off course I installed it.